# Sitecore roles required for content testing

Tags: security, content-testing

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 7 and I'm trying to restrict access to my Sitecore Content Editors. One of them wants to run a content test using the built-in testing controls. When I go to "Create a test", I can see the options of Percentage of Visitors to Expose to Test, and Confidence Level. My content editor does not see those 2 options. What role do I need to give that content editor so that they have the ability to set those options as well.

Comment: Should be "Authoring" or "Analytics Advanced Testing" role. Add one of these role to their account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content Testing has associated roles to allow different capabilities. Per the [Experience Optimization and Content Testing FAQ](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/analyzing_and_reporting/experience_optimization__content_testing/experience_optimization_and_content_testing_faq):

> There are several [security roles](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles) that provide access to different
>   levels of functionality in Experience Optimization.
>
> Authoring – enables the creation, running, and editing of tests. You
>   typically assign this role to content authors and marketers.
>
> Analytics Advanced Testing – contains the same access as the Authoring
>   role, plus additional tabs and controls. You typically assign this
>   role to marketing analysts.
>
> Analytics Management Reporting – has full access to all content
>   testing dashboards and historical reports and cannot create tests. You
>   typically assign this role to marketing directors.
>
> You can also add security roles to individual users to give them
>   access to Experience Optimization.